# Vhost: rewrite rule for php file

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have an `index.html` page for **k.example.com**. This file is located in `/var/www/html`.

There are multiple folders in /var/www/html, for example `/var/www/html/dir1`, `/var/www/html/dir2`, `/var/www/html/dir3`. They contain php files. 
When I enter `k.example.com/dir1` I need it to redirect to `login.php` file included in the dir1.

I am stuck in the RewriteRule option.

Here is my configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost    *:80>
    ServerName      k.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost    *:80>
    ServerName      k.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/html

    Alias           /dir1 /var/www/html/dir1

    RewriteEngine   on
    RewriteRule     
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: _“When I enter k.example.com/dir1 I need it to redirect to login.php file included in the dir1”_ – what, for every request (no matter if the user did login before already)? If so, why don’t you simply use DirectoryIndex?

Comment: Yes, DirectoryIndex worked.